# openssl - getting frequent ssl_read and s_write erros

Tags: c++, openssl

Windows c++ program, openssl-1.1.1g

We have a server that has around  2025 clients connected at any instant.

Our application creates a Server /Listener socket that then is converted into a Secure socket using OpenSSL library. This is compiled and built in a Windows x64 environment.  We also built OpenSSL for the Windows. The Listener socket is created with a default backlog of 500. The Accept socket is non-blocking socket and waits for connections

Every Client makes a regular blocking connection to the Server. The Server accepts the connection after which the Client socket is converted to a secure socket using the OpenSSL Library.
The connections are coming at a rate of about 10 connections /second ?  Not sure about this number.

We are able to connect to all the clients in a few minutes and it stays like that for some time.  There constant exchange of messages between Server(COS) and clients without issues.
The application logic is to keep trying to connect every timeout.
After maybe a few hours/days we see the clients dropping connections.  The logs indicate the SSL_Read or SSL_Write on the Server fails for a client with SSL_Error number 5 (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) and the equivalent Windows error of WSATimeOut.  We then observe the WSAECONNRESET as the Client closed connection.  We see this behavior for multiple sites.

The number of Clients disconnected starts increasing and we see the logs in the Client where the server refuses any more connections form Clients (10061- WSAECONNREFUSED) There is nothing to indicate this state in the server logs. Our theory is the backlog is filled and Server refusing further connections.

We are trying to find why we get the SSL_Read/SSL_Write Error as it a Blocking socket. We cannot use to a non-blocking socket due to platform and application limitation

Comment: "*The logs indicate the SSL_Read or SSL_Write on the Server fails for a client with SSL_Error number 5 (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) and the equivalent Windows error of WSATimeOut*" - that is a bit odd, especially when using non-blocking sockets, because there shouldn't be any timeout errors. Generally you should be getting `SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE)` errors instead. But it is hard to diagnose your issue without seeing your actual code.

Comment: "*The number of Clients disconnected starts increasing and we see the logs in the Client where the server refuses any more connections form Clients (10061- WSAECONNREFUSED)*" - then that means your server has likely stopped `accept()`'ing clients completely, especially with such a large backlog. Maybe you deadlocked your server, or crashed it. Again, hard to diagnose without actual code.

Comment: "*We cannot use to a non-blocking socket due to platform and application limitation*" - but you ARE using non-blocking sockets. As you said: "*The Accept socket is **non-blocking socket** and waits for connections*", and on Windows, if the listening socket is non-blocking then the socket that `accept()` returns will also be non-blocking. That is not the case on 'Nix platforms, for instance.